# Interesting algebras over non-commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, separable-extension

It would be nice to have several examples of an interesting $R$-algebra $A$, where $R$ is a non-commutative ring (plausible definitions can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring)).

One example is a polynomial ring over any non-commutative ring, 
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806119/do-polynomials-make-sense-over-non-commutative-rings).

Also, I wonder if some properties of commutative ring extensions are still valid
for two non-commutative rings, for example, 
the definition of a separable ring extension $R \subseteq A$, where $R$ is a non-commutative ring (hence $A$ is also non-commutative).
The usual definition where $R$ is a commutative ring, can be found in [this post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/) (in his notations, is it possible to just replace $k$ by a non-commutative ring? Is there a problem with tensoring over a non-commutative ring?).

**Edit:** After receiving two comments requesting me to be more precise/pick a definition, my new question is:

> Let $R \subseteq A$, $R$ is a non-commutative ring ($R$ and $A$ are associative with $1$). It would be nice to have examples of such rings with $A$ being a flat $R$-module. My example: $R$ is a division ring.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "interesting" sounds vague. Can you be more precise? What do you find interesting in an $R$-algebra?

Comment: ok, I will try to be more precise. By an interesting algebra $A$, I mean an algebra that was studied and there exist some theorems concerning it. For example, the first Weyl algebras $A_1(k)$ ($k$ is a field; what if we replace $k$ by a non-commutative ring?).

Comment: I think at the very least you're going to have to pick the definition you want to use. Asking responders to take their pick from a basket of random definitions, then provide "interesting" picks, whatever that means, is just too broad. Basically posters shouldn't have to make so many decisions about what constitutes an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try to restrict my question.

Comment: @user237522 Thanks: I think it's a big improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way to get a lot of examples:

A ring is [von Neumann regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) iff *all* of its modules are flat. So, you can pick any ring $A$ containing a von Neumann regular ring $R$, and you have an example.

A few other obvious constructions that would work for any ring $R$ include regarding $\prod_{i=1}^n R$ and $M_n(R)$ and $R[x]$ as $R$ algebras, since all are *free* hence flat modules over $R$.

Comment: I like your idea! (However, if $A$ is a domain, then $R$ is a domain, and von Neumann regularity of $R$ would imply that $R$ is a division ring, if I am not wrong).

Comment: @user237522 You are correct, a VNR domain is a division ring. I'm not very good with flatness, so i don't know what can be worked in the situation is, say for flat extensions of noncommutative domains.

Comment: In my question there was no requirement that $A$ is a domain, so your answer is really ok (and nice). Nevertheless, I am still curious to see examples when $R$ is a domain which is not a division ring.

Comment: @user237522 Mentioning also several obvious constructions which are based on free modules, and they'll work for any ring.