# Formal derivative, any problems for non-commutative rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $R\left[ x \right]$ be the ring of polynomials over $R$.

If $f=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0 \in R\left[ x \right]$, we define the formal derivative $f^{'}=na_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1$.

Let $f$ , $g$ $\in R\left[ x \right]$ and $c \in R$. Using the definition, it can be verified that:

1. $(f+g)^{'}=f^{'}+g^{'}$
2. $(cf)^{'}=cf^{'}$
3. $(f+g)^{'}=f^{'}+g^{'}$

However, I came across this passage on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative):

> There is a problem with this definition for noncommutative rings. The
> formula itself is correct, but there is no standard form of a
> polynomial. Therefore using this definition it is difficult to prove
> that $(f(x)\cdot b)^{'}=f^{'}(x)\cdot b$.

This makes me confused. I don't know what it is talking about. I don't see any problems here. The proofs of 1,2,3 for commutative rings and noncommutative rings are all the same. For example, I can easily prove that $(f\cdot b)^{'}=f^{'}\cdot b$:

Let $f_k$ denote the k-th coefficient of the polynomial $f$, $k=0,1,2\ldots$. By definition we know $(f^{'})_k=(k+1)f_{k+1}$. So $(LHS)_k=(k+1)(f\cdot b)_{k+1}=(k+1)(f_{k+1}\cdot b)=((k+1)f_{k+1})\cdot b=(f^{'})_k\cdot b=(f^{'}\cdot b)_k=(RHS)_k$. QED.

Where did I go wrong? What does the paragraph on Wikipedia mean?

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to assume that $ax^nb=abx^n$.

Comment: I think it is standard that $x$ commutes with $R$ in $R[x]$. The non-commuting version, not a polynomial ring, may be denoted $R\langle x\rangle$ or $R\{x\}$. Anyway the comment on wikipedia is misleading as only the "$x$ commuting with $R$" version is a polynomial ring, in the non-commuting one you have things like $axbx$ that don't simplify to polynomials $\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n$. In $R[x]$, $D(\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n)=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n n x^{n-1}$ is a derivation.

Comment: @markvs Where?  I dealt directly with the coefficients and didn't use the indeterminate "$x$" at all. You see, there is no "$x$" in the proof.

Comment: You seem to assume that the first coefficient  of $f(x)b$ is $f_1b$.

Comment: @markvs Yes.$(f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots) \cdot(b,0,0,\ldots)=(f_0b,f_1b,f_2b,\ldots)$. This is immediately from the definition of polynomial multiplication: $c_k=\sum_{i+j=k} a_ib_j$. Moreover, the order of $f$ and $b$ here hasn't changed. I mean $b$ is always after $f$. Sorry for my slow reply.  I'm not good at English.

Comment: @reuns Do you mean that if $R$ isn't commutative, $R\left[ x \right]$ is not a ring ?

Comment: No. The question is not if $R$ is commutative but if $xr=rx$ for all $r\in R$. If yes then it gives a polynomial ring $R[x]$ with a derivation as usual. If $R$ is non-commutative then $R[x]$ is non-commutative. You need $xr=rx$ to say that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ which makes it a derivation, not only a $R$-module map.

Comment: Your polynomial multiplication says, in particular, $(x)(b)=bx$?

Comment: @markvs  $(x)$ or $(b)$ represents?  Why adding the parentheses?

Comment: $(x)$ is the polynomial $x$. So you have $xb=bx$. Now plug every element of the ring for $x$. Thus either the ring is commutative of your polynomials do not correspond to functions $R\to R$. Both options are unfortunate.

Comment: @markvs I haven't fully understood your words and what I can explain so far is as follows: The definition of polynomial multiplication I use is standard. To avoid ambiguity, let me use "$X$" for the indeterminate of a polynomial $f$ and "$x$" for the argument of the associated polynomial function. I regard a polynomial $f$ as an infinite sequence $(f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots)$ and $X$ as the polynomial $X=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$. So I have $Xb=bX$ but don't have $xb=bx$.

Comment: So your polynomials do not correspond to functions $R\to R$?  What is the use of them then?

Comment: @markvs This question is beyond my ability :)

Comment: I do not know the canonical definition of polynomials over a non-commutative ring. What you define is some quotient of the free product $R*\Bbb Z$. Before you define something you should decide what to do with it. It does not matter how you call it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806119/do-polynomials-make-sense-over-non-commutative-rings

Comment: @markvs Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @reuns It's incredible that the non-commuting version, which I've never known before, is treated as a polynomial ring on Wikipedia. Now it’s clear to me. Thanks a million!